# print SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

¡Buenas!

Actualmente me encuentro aprendiendo Python y en una aplicación sencilla de práctica me he encontrado el siguiente error:

```
File "ruta_fichero", line 9
    print(num2, "es menor que ", str(num1))
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

El código que he escrito es el siguiente:

```
num1 = int(input("Escribe un número: "))
num2 = int(input("Escribe un número mayor que ", str(num1), ":"))

while num2 > num1:
num1 = num2
num2 = int(input("Escribe un número mayor que ", str(num1), ":")


print(num2, "es menor que ", str(num1))
```

¿Sabéis donde puede estar el error de sintaxis?

¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Muchas veces el punto donde te marca el error no es donde está, sino donde se detecta.

```
num2 = int(input("Escribe un número mayor que ", str(num1), ":")
print(num2, "es menor que ", str(num1))
```

En la línea anterior abres tres paréntesis y cierras dos.

Como no sabe que pasa, el compilador sigue procesando el fichero, intentando completar la expresión que usará en el `int()`, hasta que se encuentra con un fragmento de código que no puede encajar en lo que está haciendo (el `print(num2..`) y allí es donde marca el error.

Comment: ¡Cierto,era solo el paréntesis.! ¡Muchísimas gracias!